# Is it possible to link against a compiled Cocoa App?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Let's say I want to use some of classes within a Cocoa app, for grins, how about [Sketch](http://www.sketchapp.com/). I can use [class-dump](http://stevenygard.com/projects/class-dump/) to get a list of the headers and classes within Sketch (or by viewing their [documentation](http://www.sketchapp.com/support/developer/)). Is it possible to link to one of those classes from within my own code? For example, I'd like to walk their [`MSPage`](http://www.sketchapp.com/support/developer/03-reference/MSPage.html) class in my own code.

And to make it harder, let's say this would need to be apps from the Mac App Store or downloaded from somewhere.

Comment: I want some of what's being smoked here! :) Seriously, isn't this exactly the sort of code injection that Apple is racing to shut down?

Comment: Not looking to inject code into their process. I'm building a Sketch plugin and would like to use their models within an ObjC framework instead of messing around in Cocoascript. I've seen other solutions that create proxies, but that's... tedious. https://github.com/JohnCoates/CSSketch

Comment: If that's possible, then what would be the point of their sandboxing MAS applications?

Comment: If you're building a bundle that's intended to be loaded by Sketch, you could link it using the `-bundle_loader <executable>` linker flag. However, a release build of Sketch likely has had some of the necessary symbols stripped, so that won't work.